# Access 2007, possibly VBA: issue with having to fill out too many fields

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

This issue is a bit complicated to explain so please bear with me. I have a **COMP** table. This table houses the salaries of employees. I also have an **Emp Table.** See below:

```
  **COMP Table**                                **Empl Table**
  ID:         Year:       Salary:               ID:        Region:
  1           2013        $50000                1          USA
  1           2012        $45000                2          Canada
  1           2011        $40000
  etc..       etc..       etc..
  2           2013        $45000
  etc..       etc..       etc..
```

Each salary has its own year. So my **problem** is that when I create a **new employee** I have to fill out all the years from **2006-2013** for my **queries and reports to work.** Is there any way I can auto fill the years with no information? Can I use VBA for this?

**Summary:** What is the best way to create a new employee so I don't have to fill out all the **COMP** table for them (but still have queries, forms, and reports work).

Answer (score 1):

You could almost certainly use some VBA magic to automatically populate the [COMP] table with dummy records "back to the beginning of time", but a better solution would be to adjust your queries and reports to handle the case where such records do not exist. It would be silly to back-fill the [COMP] table with seven years of junk data (Salary = 0) for every new hire, and the problem would just get worse as time goes by (e.g., you would have to back-fill eight years of junk starting in 2014) and as the number of new/replacement employees increases.

Comment: My main report is the totals for salary. A table doesn't usually hold a totals column. I have a query that holds totals. It combiens the two tables so I can search SALARY TOTAL by REGION. But it doesn't work if I don't have all the years in it. So the report doesn't work.

Comment: If you make a new query, it will! You can make a query on all year in Comp and left join it to comp and empl table. That would be the right way, and not filing dummy data in database!!!